# Coldfusion output variable as image from database

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

this function upload the photo in a map in our network. after that its sets the path of the photo and puts the source in imagepath.

```
    <cffunction name="uploadphoto" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">

            <cfif isDefined("myForm.Submit")>
                <returnvariable="imagePath">
            </cfif>

        <cfparam name="form.fileUpload" default="">

        <cfif len(trim(form.fileUpload))>
            <cfset LOCAL.imagePath = 'img/profiles/' />
            <cfset strPath = ExpandPath( "./" ) & LOCAL.imagePath /> 

            <cffile action="upload"
             fileField="fileUpload"
             destination="#strPath#"
             nameconflict="overwrite">

          <p>Thankyou, your file has been uploaded.</p>
        </cfif>
        <cfset form.filename = CFFILE.serverfile>


        <cfreturn LOCAL.imagePath & form.filename/>

        </cffunction>  

This function update's the database and puts the img source path (imagePath) in the database.



    <cffunction name="savephoto" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
                    <cfargument name="dbname"   type="any" required="no" default="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDBName()#" />
                    <cfargument name="myForm" type="Struct" required="yes">
                    <cfargument name="imagePath" type="any" required="yes">

                    <cfquery name="upload" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">

                    UPDATE logboek.tbl_users SET photo=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.imagePath#"/>
                    WHERE Users_id=<cfqueryparam value="#SESSION.Login_logboek.User_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                    </cfquery>

        </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="checkavatar" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
                <cfargument name="dbname"   type="any" required="no" default="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDBName()#" />

                <cfquery name="checkavatar" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">

This function checks if the right user is logged in to see the photo.

                    SELECT photo FROM logboek.tbl_users WHERE Users_id=<cfqueryparam value="#SESSION.Login_logboek.User_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
                </cfquery>

    <cfif checkavatar.RecordCount eq 1>
        <cfreturn checkavatar.photo />
    </cfif>


    </cffunction>
```

my problem lies in the view i want to use the image source his path from the database to output the image on the screen VARIABLES.checkavatar needs to return "photo" from the database like so:

```
<cfoutput>
#VARIABLES.checkavatar#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: `checkavatar` is a function - so you need to call it as such. For example `theCFCInstance.checkavatar()`. On a separate note, where possible, functions should only use variables that are passed to them or are available to the containing CFC instance. So scopes like form, session, server should be passed into the function or instance of the CFC. You also need to `var scope` variables created inside a function.

Comment: You may already know this but, outputting the function results won't give you the photo, it will just give to the path to it.  You'll need an img tag as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things going wrong here.

First and foremost, within the function `checkavatar`, you are reassigning the variable `checkavatar` to a query result. Effectively, this destroys the function the first time it is called. Due to CF's weird scoping rules, you need to first include a line like `<cfset var checkavatar = -1>` in the function before you do the query. I would further recommend not naming the variable the same thing as the function it is in.

Your call to the function should end up looking something like

```
<img src="#checkavatar()#"/>
```

since that function returns the path. You may have additional problems sorting out the difference between your local to the file and the web-accessible path to the file, but this is hard to debug remotely.

Next, get rid of the `<cfif checkavatar.RecordCount eq 1>` check, or modify it to handle that case. If you just `<cfreturn checkavatar.photo />` the worst you will get back is an empty string if nothing is found. Currently, you will return nothing at all, and this will crash the page which calls it. So either throw explicitly or return a default avatar image.

Finally, only use variables passed into the function as arguments (as opposed to passing in variables via `session` like is being done now). This is much better design and will be easier to reuse later.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cffunction name="uploadphoto" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">

    <cfif isDefined("myForm.Submit")>
        <returnvariable="imagePath">
    </cfif>

<cfparam name="form.fileUpload" default="">

<cfif len(trim(form.fileUpload))>
    <cfset LOCAL.imagePath = 'img/profiles/' />
    <cfset strPath = ExpandPath( "./" ) & LOCAL.imagePath /> 

    <cffile action="upload"
     fileField="fileUpload"
     destination="#strPath#"
     nameconflict="overwrite">

  <p>Thankyou, your file has been uploaded.</p>
</cfif>
<cfset form.filename = CFFILE.serverfile>


<cfreturn LOCAL.imagePath & form.filename/>

</cffunction>


<cffunction name="savephoto" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
            <cfargument name="dbname"   type="any" required="no" default="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDBName()#" />
            <cfargument name="myForm" type="Struct" required="yes">
            <cfargument name="imagePath" type="any" required="yes">

            <cfquery name="upload" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">

            UPDATE logboek.tbl_users SET photo=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.imagePath#"/>
            WHERE Users_id=<cfqueryparam value="#SESSION.Login_logboek.User_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            </cfquery>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="checkavatar" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
            <cfargument name="dbname"   type="any" required="no" default="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDBName()#" />

            <cfquery name="checkavatar" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">

                SELECT photo FROM logboek.tbl_users WHERE Users_id=<cfqueryparam value="#SESSION.Login_logboek.User_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
            </cfquery>

<cfif checkavatar.RecordCount eq 1>
    <cfreturn checkavatar.photo />
</cfif>



</cffunction>


<cfif IsDefined ("VARIABLES.checkavatar")>

<cfoutput>
<img src="#VARIABLES.checkavatar#"
</cfoutput>

<cfelse>

    <cfoutput>
        Error       
    </cfoutput>

</cfif>
```